# How to receive Soap response in php

Tags: php, soap

However, what I want is to be able to get response request and populate PHP

I already did that using soapUI and got the response in xml format like

```
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://bsestarmfdemo.bseindia.com/2016/01/IMFUploadService/MFAPIResponse</a:Action>
      <a:RelatesTo>uuid:804ed18e-630f-4b16-86ee-6f97ee71743e</a:RelatesTo>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <MFAPIResponse xmlns="http://bsestarmfdemo.bseindia.com/2016/01/">
         <MFAPIResult>100|PAYMENT NOT INITIATED FOR GIVEN ORDER</MFAPIResult>
      </MFAPIResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**MY PHP Code**

I don’t have much experience with SOAP but am required to build a validator for my work and using a specific SOAP wsdl.

I’ve set up the connect

```
<?php
$url= "http://bsestarmfdemo.bseindia.com/StarMFFileUploadService/StarMFFileUploadService.svc?wsdl";
  $method = "MFAPI";
  $error=0;
  $fault=0;
  $client = new SoapClient($url, array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2 , 'SoapAction'=>'http://tempuri.org/IStarMFFileUploadService/MFAPI'));

  $actionHeader= array();
  $actionHeader[] = new SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing',
                                 'Action',
                                 'http://tempuri.org/IStarMFFileUploadService/MFAPI');
  $actionHeader[] = new SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing',
                                 'To',
                                 'http://bsestarmfdemo.bseindia.com/MFUploadService/MFUploadService.svc/Basic');
  $client->__setSoapHeaders($actionHeader);


  $featchData = array('Param' => array('UserId' => 'xxxxx', 'Flag' => 'xxxx', 'EncryptedPassword' => 'xxxx', 'param' => 'xxxx') );


    try{ 
      $resultData = $client->__call($method, array($featchData));

      } 
    catch (SoapFault $resultData)  { 
          $error = 1; 
         }

   if($error==1) {

       $result=$fault;
   }else{
      $result = $resultData;
      var_dump($result);
     }
  // echo $result;
   ?>
```

Comment: What issue you are facing with that code ? Are you getting any error?

Comment: Undefined variable: fault in C:\xampp\htdocs\test1.php on line 32 and no receive any response

Comment: Which is line 32 in the code?